# Moving from HD to RAM without involving CPU?

Tags: architecture

I am learning architecture of x86 and as I understand that all times when we execute any program we take it from HD into RAM, so in book's diagram there isn't any activities of CPU. Does it mean that moving from HD to RAM doesn't involve any CPU power?
And it is related to other I/O devices.In the book it is written that file is copied from main memory to the display device.Is there any CPU instruction?

To tell the truth, I suppose that it will be impossible to do anything without executing instructions, but this book makes me think about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of those "it depends" situation.

Many computers support something called "direct memory access" (or DMA), where some devices can send data across the memory bus without the CPU being involved (outside setting the DMA transfer up). This can be bidirectional, so it could be either "memory to peripheral" or "peripheral to memory".

For displays, it's potentially even more complicated. It is entirely possible that the CPU has no access to the memory that the display is driven from. Or it may be that it is double-port memory (meaning that the graphics controller and the CPU can both access the RAM at the same time). It can be the CPU "bit-banging" the display cable, or it could be done with the CPU being stalled as the graphic controller.

So, yes, it is possible. But it really depends on the motherboard, the controllers involved, the operating system involved, the driver software for the controller, and probably more factors.

Comment: Thank you, it is really useful.But can you explain to me with an example such as Unix system, x86_64 process.